# Check if a coordinate point are lies in certain box area python

Tags: python, maps, coordinate

I have a coordinate point of a place, for example:

```
point_coord = [-7.7938593,110.3634829]
```

I also have a `viewport` of an area contain two point of corrdinates, for example:

```
northeast = [5.9052479,141.0194444]
southwest = [-11.005261,95.01106190000002]
```

If I illustrate these point, it will be look like this:
[image]

The question is, how do I check if the `point_coord` is fall or lies in somewhere in that box area using Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, not too much experience with maps and viewports, but shouldn't it simply be:

```
def isInside(point_coord, northeast, southwest):
    return southwest[0]<point_coord[0]<northeast[0] and\
           southwest[1]<point_coord[1]<northeast[1]
```

The only possible edge cases I can think of would be north and south poles. You could probably just code special cases to handle them.

Edit: some typos and not chaining comparisons.