# Iterate through address CSV to find if address is in an area

Tags: python, user-interface, gis

thanks for any help yall can give me. I'm having a hard time knowing where to start for this project.

I have a list of addresses in CSV format. I need to create a GUI that a user can type an address in and it will tell them if they are serviceable in an area. It would be extremely nice if I could turn it into an executable.

I have a polygon that the addresses need to land in. I was planning on plotting all of the addresses on ARCGIS and then selecting them to create a list of addresses that are in the area. The addresses have a lat and long.

Comment: There is a lot to unpack in this question for which no individual answer will suffice.  I suggest taking your overall problem and breaking it down to the various components and asking directed, pointed questions after performing your research.  I suggest starting with looking at `pandas` and working on your familiarity with that module and data frame manipulation.  Once comfortable, move on to the next objective.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Try converting the address into lat and long coordinates, and then check, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180019/check-if-a-coordinate-point-are-lies-in-certain-box-area-python .      Best.

Answer (score 0):

This will give rough idea where to start :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing, Polygon
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#reading data
data = pd.read_csv('address.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#initialization
lat = np.asarray(df['lat'])
long = np.asarray(df['long'])
poly_cords = [(2, 9), (2, 6), (5, 5), (6, 9)]
address = df['address']

#visualization
poly = Polygon(poly_cords)
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.scatter(lat,long)
plt.plot(x, y, color='#6699cc', alpha=0.7,
    linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)
plt.show()

#function to produce proximity results
def call_result(label_result, n1, n2, poly_cords):
    lat = (n1.get())
    long = (n2.get())
    lat = float(lat)
    long = float(long)
    point = Point(lat,long)
    polygon = Polygon(poly_cords)
    if polygon.contains(point) == False:
        x = "We do not serve here"
    else:
        x = "we serve here"
    label_result.config(text="Result is %s" % x)
    return

#GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x200+100+200')
root.title('Address Proximity')
number1 = tk.StringVar()
number2 = tk.StringVar()
labelTitle = tk.Label(root, text="Address Proximity").grid(row=0, column=2)
labelNum1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter a lat").grid(row=1, column=0)
labelNum2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter long").grid(row=2, column=0)
labelResult = tk.Label(root)
labelResult.grid(row=7, column=2)
entryNum1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number1).grid(row=1, column=2)
entryNum2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number2).grid(row=2, column=2)
call_result = partial(call_result, labelResult, number1, number2, polygon_cordinates)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=call_result).grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

As per your problem GUI is generated which takes latitude and longitude as input. The (lat,long) is tested for being present inside the polygon. If present it will display "We serve here" else it will display "We do not serve here". You can change the co-ordinates of polygon according to your requirement. 
The polygon looks like :
[image]